# Vue.js: Give a nested property/attribute a custom value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

In my view (HTML) I want to show this:

`<p>Age: {{ user.age }} years</p>`

In my javascript this is what I have:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#userApp',

    data: {
        user       : user,
        alergies   : user.alergies,
        conditions : user.conditions,
        drugs      : user.drugs,
        solicitudes: solicitudes,
    },

    computed: {

    },

    filters: {
        active: function(elements) {
            return elements.filter(function(element){
                return ! element.fecha_fin;
            });
        }
    },

    methods: {

    }

});
```

How do I modify the age in the computed properties? I tried doing this

```
computed: {
    user.age: 10        
},
```

but it won't allow it.

Note: I'm getting `user, solicitudes` from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties are functions that you use as properties.

In your case, I think that you can use age like you're doing with the drugs or conditions. Than the 2 way data bindings take care of that.

```
data: {
    user       : user,
    alergies   : user.alergies,
    conditions : user.conditions,
    drugs      : user.drugs,
    age        : user.age,
    solicitudes: solicitudes,
}
```

Based on your comment bellow, maybe you can use this:

```
compiled: {
    user[age] = theAgeOfTheUser
}
```

That method will create a new property on the user object. Then you can modify like any other value.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but wasn't what I was looking for. I want to access age as a property of user, hence the `user.age`.

Comment: Ok. I think then you can use:
    compiled: {
     user[age] = age;
}

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work, I think is just the structure of javascript that won't let it happen. BTW, the error says: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`